# How can I store decimal value with localStorage in setInterval function and also change the "dot" to "comma"?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, setinterval

I'm trying to create countUp value based on per /second time. It will keep counting (adding my "customRate" value) even when the page is refreshed. But, the second value after the "dot" will not restore if I refresh the page, it will start again from "customRate value".
any solution for this?
and the second question is, how to change the "dot" to "comma" in this code?

Thanks

Here is my code :

```js
var impulse = 0;
tmpImpulse = localStorage.getItem('impulseFix1')
if (tmpImpulse != null) {
  impulse = parseInt(tmpImpulse, 10);
}
setInterval(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('impulseFix1', impulse)
  customRate = 0.046
  impulse = impulse + customRate;
  document.getElementById("impulse").innerHTML = impulse.toFixed(3) + " impulse/second";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="impulse" style="color:red"> </span>
```

Comment: You mean the decimals are being removed from the number? Then use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks, and how about changing the decimal separator into "comma"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here
When happy remove the `let impulse = 0.5; // testing`

and uncomment the localStorage lines

```js
// let impulse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('impulseFix1'));
let impulse = 0.5; // testing
const customRate = 0.046
if (impulse != null) {
  impulse = +impulse; // do not parseInt here, your decimals will go
}
setInterval(function() {
  impulse += customRate;
 //   localStorage.setItem('impulseFix1', JSON.stringify(impulse))
  document.getElementById("impulse").innerHTML = impulse.toFixed(3).replace(".",",") + " impulse/second";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="impulse" style="color:red"> </span>
```

Comment: @Abosiiqi I modified slightly to save AFTER incrementing